# Linux does not NAT IPs without defining as IP alias

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have a Linux router like:

İnternet <-> Linux <-> DMZ

We have /25 subnet of 128 IP addresses. Those are NATed into servers in DMZ. If I did not configure all of these IP addresses as IP aliases in external interface of Linux, those IPs did not work.

Lets example,
212.123.123.45 IP is not defined in Linux. I see packets targeted to 212.123.123.45 at external interface of Linux with tcpdump. However, NAT rules does not work.
If I define 212.123.123.45 as eth1:1 at external interface, NAT rules start to work.

Kernel is 2.6.18 latest Centos 5.5 kernel.

I need your kind comments.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

My comment is your network as working as NAT is designed.  Without configuring the public IP address for the NAT, the NAT cannot work.

Interface alias is one way to solve the addressing problem.  For a more modern ip addressing tool, please see [iproute2](http://lartc.org/howto/).

Comment: The important point is packets are already routed by frontend router. I see the packets in incoming interface already. The point is that, NAT does not work until I add the destiation IP as IP alias.

Comment: Routing is necessary but not sufficient.  You need the destination as you've learned.

Comment: This is al Lİnux router. It should be able to process(route, NAT etc) packets not destined to itself.

Comment: You have two choices: either NAT as you mention above, or route the IP to the target.  If you NAT, the public IP must live on the NAT device.  It seems you need to read and understand the Linux NAT howto, specifically: http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//NAT-HOWTO-9.html.  While that section pertains more directly to SNAT and you are speaking above more about DNAT, the requirement still holds.

Comment: Actually I read most ofthe howto. The specific page says the packets you NATed should come back to you for deNAT. No problem. In my case I am already the router and all of the packets has to come to my router.

Comment: "all the packets has to come to my router" is where you are going wrong.  See: http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html  Something needs to ARP for that IP address.  You are wrongly assuming that routing=ARP.